# How to apply multiple styles to a div by using $(element).css(styles)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have to apply multiple styles to a div my code is as under:

```
$(".myDiv").css("background","none");
$(".myDiv").css("background-position","left top");
$(".myDiv").css("background-repeat","repeat-x");
```

I want to write them once rather than repeating .css() function...

Comment: `$(".myDiv").css({"background":"none", "background-position":"left top"});` always go through [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css-properties) before posting a question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should try this.

```
$(".myDiv").css({
'background':'none',
'background-position':'left top',
'background-repeat':'repeat-x',
});
```

am sure will work...

Comment: thanks waseem, its working...